# Flutter Local Notification app icon not showing on pixel 6 phone but others app is ok

Tags: flutter, notifications, pixel, local

Flutter Local Notification app icon not showing on pixel 6  phone but others app is ok

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'channel ID',
      'channel name',
      playSound: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
    );
    await flutterNotificationPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = const DarwinInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await flutterNotificationPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
    );
```

Comment: did you define the icon in manifest like this <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    ...
> ?

Comment: yes. this is my manifest 

<application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

Comment: or try to ensure that the @mipmap/ic_launcher value in your AndroidInitializationSettings is pointing to the correct mipmap folder ..

Comment: You can use adaptive icons to show icons in notifications.